# Help with the installation of Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: dual-boot

I'm trying to download ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop which is currently running windows 7. I want to install to where I can dual boot either.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explain more in detail, I am assuming you already have downloaded the Ubuntu ISO file and you want to setup a dual boot with your windows OS.
to do so I'd suggest you follow the instruction mentioned here.

**First Backup**

**Install Ubuntu after installing windows**

A Windows OS should be installed first, because its boot loader is very particular and the installer tends to overwrite the entire hard drive, wiping out any data stored on it. If Windows isn’t already installed, install it first. If you are able to partition the drive prior to installing Windows, leave space for Ubuntu during the initial partitioning process. Then you won’t have to resize your NTFS partition to make room for Ubuntu later, saving a bit of time.

When a Windows installation already occupies the entire hard drive, its partition needs to be shrunk, creating free space for the Ubuntu partition. You can do this during the Ubuntu installation procedure.

then create separate partition

Go To “Computer Management”.

[image]

1.2 Go To “Disk Management”.

[image]

1.3 Right Click on Disk you want to Partitioned, Select “Shrink Volume”.
[image]

1.4 Enter the amount of space to shrink in MB. Then click Shrink. This will create New Partitioned Disk with disk amount entered by you.

[image]

Once done you need to reboot and boot from your Ubuntu Live CD or USB (Read this for more info: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest)

When you are ready to install Ubuntu on your hard disk, click the Install Ubuntu button. The installation wizard will appear:
[image]
[image]
Click Continue

and select the desired options. Click Continue. The Installation type window appears.

**Installation Type**

If you want to install Ubuntu alongside you other systems (eg alongside Windows), select the Install Ubuntu alongside them.
[image]

then Click Continue and follow the on screen instructions.

For more info Have a look on these pages:

- http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2014/02/01/dual-boot-windows-8-or-windows-7-and-ubuntu-13-10-with-ubuntu-on-a-btrfs-filesystem/
- http://techsultan.com/install-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot-windows-7-8/
- http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest